# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2839, 14195]

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

before this dataset all the previous ones worked fine, now with this new dataset it rais the below errors, I tried to reshape the X_train but it is not attributed for X_trian, anyone can help. thank you

```
feature_df = pd.read_excel('thedatasets/boutput.xlsx')
    Y = pd.get_dummies(feature_df['class'],drop_first=True)
    X = feature_df.drop(['class'],axis=1)
```

## the below code is in other py file

```
for i in range(np.shape(generation)[0]):
            individual = generation[i, :]

            # Subset the columns based on this individual
            X_individual = self.dataset[[self.dataset.columns[j] for j in range(len(individual)) if individual[j] == 1]]

            # Split into train-test datasets
            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_individual, self.response, test_size=self.test_size)

            # Fit the classifier

            self.algorithm.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
            grid.fit(X_train,y_train.values.ravel())
```

**the Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cinci/Desktop/SPLITPROJ/GeneticAlgorithmExample.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/cinci/Desktop/SPLITPROJ/GeneticAlgorithmExample.py", line 17, in main
    GA.fit()
  File "/Users/cinci/Desktop/SPLITPROJ/GeneticAlgorithm.py", line 167, in fit
    old_fitness_array = self.fitness(old_generation)
  File "/Users/cinci/Desktop/SPLITPROJ/GeneticAlgorithm.py", line 77, in fitness
    self.algorithm.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
  File "/Users/cinci/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py", line 148, in fit
    accept_large_sparse=True)
  File "/Users/cinci/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 765, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "/Users/cinci/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 212, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2839, 14195]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that 14916 / 5 is 2839, I'm assuming that the cause of your issue is that you have more than one output label (5 labels) and you're using .ravel()

This will flatten your data and the model will think you're trying to pass in # of labels * number_of_training_examples examples as your training examples.

To fix this, instead of using .ravel() you should reshape your final y_train so it has a shape of number_of_training_examples x number_of_labels